# How to filter out usercreated events in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar where I display non-editable events which are collected from a google calendar, or from a database. Then I want to register customer requests for events from the calendar. This works, but I am not able to list only the events that are added by the user.
Any hint on how to do this?
I tried this:

```
function retrieve_events() {

    var rdv=$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents', undefined);
    for (i=0; i<=rdv.length-1; i++) {
        /*alert(rdv.toSource());*/
        alert(rdv[i].title+" id: "+rdv[i].id+" start: "+rdv[i].start+" end:"+rdv[i].end+" heldag:"+rdv[i].allDay);
    }
}
```

The the "undefined" as id, means that I have given all the non-editable events an id, while the new ones haven't got one. But this way I get all events listed, even those without an id. The same happens with null and ''. But using hardcoded id-numbers returns that specific event.

I see from the documentation that there seems to be other ways to get hold of the events I need, by using other criteria like classes. However I cannot figure out how to specify this filter.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with *FullCalendar* yet nor do I intend to extensively test this, so I cannot guarantee that this will work.

However, why don't you simple test whether `rdv[i].id` evaluates to false?

Try:

```
function retrieve_events( ) {
    var rdv = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents'),
        results = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < rdv.length; ++i ) {
        if( !rdv[i].id ) {
            results.push(rdv[i]);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

P.S.: Passing `undefined` to `.fullCalendar()` probably is redundant. It would be equivalent to passing only a single variable. I'd guess the second parameter is a type of events that you can filter for, but passing only a single parameter would cause the plugin to return **all** events. Also, note that `!!'' === false`.

The internal check whether the second parameter is set is probably similar to this:

```
$.fn.fullCalendar = function( command ) {
    switch( command ) {
        // ... some case's
        case 'clientEvents':
            var filter = arguments[1];
            if( !filter ) {
                // Retrieve ALL client events
            }
            else {
                // Filter client events
            }
            break;
        // ... some more case's
    }
};
```

This does not compare types. Testing `filter === false` would only return true, if `filter` would evaluate to `false` **and** is a boolean.

Following are examples of values that evaluate to `false`. There may be more, but I believe those are all.

- `undefined`
- `null`
- `0`
- `false`
- `''`

Comment: Your suggestion works like a charm! 
Nevertheless, I think maybe your guess about the second argument is mistaken, as the argument is either an id or a filter. The id works on single events, while the filter option I cannot figure out how to use. It sure would be very useful, if someone could give an example.